# quaternion creation by spherical coords in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, quaternions

While trying to understand the usage the quaternion extension of numpy, I saw that

```
import numpy as np
import quaternion as q

theta = np.pi * 1.0 / 3.0
phi = 0.0

print(q.from_spherical_coords(theta,phi))
```

prints out

```
(quaternion(0.866025403784439, -0, 0.5, 0))
```

This quaternion is a 60 degrees rotation around Y axis, but I expected a 60 degrees rotation around Z axis only, since phi is 0.0. Have theta and phi changed with respect to source files or am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't understand how you are hoping to get 3D coordinates from only 2 scalar parameters. There seem to be a lack of information here.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, q.from_spherical_coords returns the quaternion that rotates from origin (theta=0,phi=0, the unit sphere N pole) to the point on the unit sphere having the given theta and phi coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding to quaternion is totally correct. But I think maybe you are confused by how `theta` and `phi` are used in spherical coordinate system.

See the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), this convention is well-known. For `theta = 60`, `phi = 0`, the point is located in zx-plane with a 60 degree angle to z-axis. Thus you do need a rotation around y-axis by 60 degree to transport the north-pole to this point.